# MongoDB listCollections filter

Tags: mongodb

I am working with node.js

I am trying to filter the collections I have to exclude the collection 'outlets' and retrieve all other collections, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax. I've tried:

```
db.listCollections({filter: 'outlets'}).toArray((err, docs)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to debug that line to see what it's doing?

Comment: I tried debugging it, It doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't return any results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filter is mis-constructed. Instead of saying 'filter', you have to specify the field to filter by name in a filter document, like this for example:

```
db.listCollections({name: 'outlets'});
```

That will include only the outlets collection, however. To *exclude* the outlets collection, you need to use the [$ne operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

```
db.listCollections({name: {$ne: 'outlets'}});
```

See the guidance in the [docs on the listCollections command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#dbcmd.listCollections) for more details.

Comment: Hey Vince, this solution make it so that that it exclusively shows collections named outlet, what is required is the opposite, show every collection that is not named 'outlets'